# How to access Flutter BLoC state value in the new version?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, state-management, flutter-bloc

I am new in this state management world. So I was trying to follow this tutorial ([How to Save Products in a Wishlist using the BloC Pattern - EP10 - The eCommerce Series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GFEwmyMeUSE&list=PLCAZyR6zw2px5C7L2cCG4aywx6g58MIoP&index=10)), but mapEventToState is deprecated so I am not sure what to do.

Here is my state:

```
part of 'wishlist_bloc.dart';

abstract class WishlistState extends Equatable {
  const WishlistState();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class WishlistLoading extends WishlistState {}

class WishlistLoaded extends WishlistState {
  final WishlistModel wishlist;

  const WishlistLoaded({this.wishlist = const WishlistModel()});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [wishlist];
}

class WishlistError extends WishlistState {}
```

Here is my event:

```
part of 'wishlist_bloc.dart';

abstract class WishlistEvent extends Equatable {
  const WishlistEvent();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class StartWishlist extends WishlistEvent {}

class AddWishlistProduct extends WishlistEvent {
  final ProductModel product;

  const AddWishlistProduct(this.product);

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [product];
}

class RemoveWishlistProduct extends WishlistEvent {
  final ProductModel product;

  const RemoveWishlistProduct(this.product);

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [product];
}
```

Here is my bloc:

```
import '../models/product_model.dart';
import '../models/wishlist_model.dart';

import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

part 'wishlist_event.dart';
part 'wishlist_state.dart';

class WishlistBloc extends Bloc<WishlistEvent, WishlistState> {
  WishlistBloc() : super(WishlistLoading()) {
    on<StartWishlist>(_mapStartWishlistToState);
    on<AddWishlistProduct>(_mapAddWishlistToState);
    on<RemoveWishlistProduct>(_mapRemoveWishlistToState);
  }

  void _mapStartWishlistToState(event, emit) async {
    emit(WishlistLoading());

    try {
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
      emit(WishlistLoaded());
    } catch (_) {}
  }

  // Error ...

  void _mapAddWishlistToState(event, emit) async {
    if (state is WishlistLoaded) {
      try {
        emit(WishlistLoaded(
            wishlist: WishlistModel(
                products: List.from(state.wishlist.products)
                  ..add(event.product))));
      } catch (_) {}
    }
  }

  void _mapRemoveWishlistToState(event, emit) async {}
}
```

But I get this error instead: "The getter 'wishlist' isn't defined for the type 'WishlistState'. Try importing the library that defines 'wishlist', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field name 'wishlist'".

How to access 'wishlist' in the new version of flutter_bloc? Thank you.

Comment: I figure it out! The only thing that you need to do is casting the state. (state as WishlistLoaded).wishlist.products

Answer (score 0):

Try to define arguments types while difining the functions. So your updated code would look like this:

```dart
import '../models/product_model.dart';
import '../models/wishlist_model.dart';

import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

part 'wishlist_event.dart';
part 'wishlist_state.dart';

class WishlistBloc extends Bloc<WishlistEvent, WishlistState> {
  WishlistBloc() : super(WishlistLoading()) {
    on<StartWishlist>(_mapStartWishlistToState);
    on<AddWishlistProduct>(_mapAddWishlistToState);
    on<RemoveWishlistProduct>(_mapRemoveWishlistToState);
  }

  void _mapStartWishlistToState(
     // Added argument types below
     StartWishlist event, Emitter<WishlistState> emit) async {
    emit(WishlistLoading());

    try {
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
      emit(WishlistLoaded());
    } catch (_) {}
  }

  void _mapAddWishlistToState(
     // Added argument types below
     AddWishlistProduct event, Emitter<WishlistState> emit) async {
    if (state is WishlistLoaded) {
      try {
        emit(WishlistLoaded(
            wishlist: WishlistModel(
                products: List.from(state.wishlist.products)
                  ..add(event.product))));
      } catch (_) {}
    }
  }

  void _mapRemoveWishlistToState(
     // Added argument types below
      RemoveWishlistProduct event, Emitter<WishlistState> emit) async {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Type promotion is impossible for properties, since they can potentially return different values each time they are called.  As such, it is impossible for the compiler to know that the `state` getter will return a `WishlistLoaded` instance, even after knowing that the same getter returned a `WishlistLoaded` four lines earlier.

One way around this is to assign the state to a local variable, which is eligible for type promotion.

```dart
  void _mapAddWishlistToState(AddWishlistProduct event, Emitter<WishlistState> emit) async {
    final state = this.state; // local variable
    if (state is WishlistLoaded) {
      try {
        emit(WishlistLoaded(
            wishlist: WishlistModel(
                products: List.from(state.wishlist.products)
                  ..add(event.product))));
      } catch (_) {}
    }
  }
```

The linked video used a parameter, which is also eligible for type promotion.  If it had used the `state` getter directly in `_mapAddWishlistProductToState`, it would have run into the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to cast your state as following

```
void _mapAddWishlistToState(event, emit) async {
    if (state is WishlistLoaded) {
      try {
        emit(WishlistLoaded(
            wishlist: WishlistModel(
                products: List.from((state as WishlistLoaded).wishlist.products)
                  ..add(event.product))));
      } catch (_) {}
    }
  }
```